How to Build a Risk Cube in Grafana Apache eCharts
I am trying to build a 2D Risk Cube, also called a Risk Matrix, in Grafana.  I think the best visualization would be in Apache eCharts, as a Scatter Graph with a background image representing the Risk Matrix, something like: https://acqnotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Risk-Matrix-Plot.png.  Apache eCharts appears to be the only dashboard visualization that supports background images, but I am open to other suggestions.  I am working in Grafana v9.2.10, with the Apache eCharts dashboard hooked up to an Elasticsearch data source (details not included).
The problem with this approach is that as the dashboard resizes, the image doesn't automatically resize also, is there a way to do this?  Or, is there an ability to somehow apply a Heatmap visualization, in place of the background image, but still with the same coloring scheme, with the Scatter graph of the risks on top of it?
let prob = [],
    like = [];

const series = data.series.map((s) => {
  prob = s.fields.find((f) => f.name === "probability").values.buffer;
  prob = s.fields.find((f) => f.name === "likelihood").values.buffer;
});

return {
  graphic: {
    type: 'image',
    style: {
      image: '/public/img/RiskDashboard/Risk-Matrix.png',
      width: 740,
      height: 525
    },
  },
  grid: {
    containsLabel: true,
    bottom: "3%",
    left: "3%",
    right: "4%",
    top: "4%"
  },
  xAxis: { min: 0, max: 5 },
  yAxis: { min: 0, max: 5 },
  targets : [
    { ... }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      symbolSize: 20,
      data: [
        prob, like
      ],
    }
  ]
};

This works, but as I said before, if you resize the dashboard, the image doesn't automatically resize also.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!
